# aws step function activity failed to be triggered

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, state-machine, aws-step-functions

I have the following piece of script which continuously pool an activity ARN
for new step functions that are triggered. I also have a cloudwatch event trigger that triggers every 1 minute.

```
import boto3
import time

region = 'ap-southeast-1'
activity_arn = 'xxxxxxxx'  #correct arn is filled here

while True:
    client = boto3.client('stepfunctions', region_name=region)
    response = client.get_activity_task(activityArn=activity_arn,
                                        workerName='daily_market_data_batch')    
    activity_token = response['taskToken']
    input_params = json.loads(response['input'])

    # simulating running some long tasks by sending heartbeats
    for i in range(10):
        client.send_task_heartbeat(taskToken=activity_token)
        time.sleep(1)

    print("================")
    print(input_params)
    client.send_task_success(taskToken=activity_token, output='true')
```

This is how the state machine is set up

```
{
  "Comment": "An example using a Task state.",
  "StartAt": "getGreeting",
  "Version": "1.0",
  "TimeoutSeconds": 300,
  "States":
  {
    "getGreeting": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:ap-southeast-1:XXXXXXXXXX:activity:get_greeting",
      "End": true
    }
}
```

What I expect to see:

Because the script has a never ending while loop, I will expect the script to be run whenever a new step function is triggered by cloud watch. When each step function runs, I expect to see the respective print out on my script's server side for "input_params".

What I actually observe:

The cloud watch did get triggered step function every 1 minute as specified. However, my script didn't catch all step function run. As you could see sometimes a step function timed out. On my script's server, there is no print out for those missed step function run.

[image]

I need to ensure my activity script never misses any step function triggered. Could anyone point out what is the cause of some step function run failed to be captured on my script server side? Thank you very much.